# Mysql - Trying to get just one result back in a union

Tags: mysql, union, multilingual

What Im trying to do is query the database to get all the channels for my site based on the site language selected. So there is a table in the db for all channels. There is a second table that holds all the channel content, based on the language that content is assigned to. So lets say I want one channel available in english and spanish, so there would be a single record in the channel table, then in the channel_local table there are 2 entries, both having the same channel id from the main channel table but one entry with the english version of the channel and the second the spanish version of the channel. How could I query the main channel table and based on the current language selected for the site get that language version of the channel from the channel_local table, but if no results found it defaults to the default language for the site all within one query? I thought a union would work but it gets both english and spanish version. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
channel_local.channelid,
channel_local.channelname,
channel.channelorder
FROM channel
INNER JOIN channel_local ON
channel.id = channel_local.channelid
WHERE channel.active = 1
AND channel_local.languageid = {currentlanguageid}
UNION
SELECT 
channel_local.channelid,
channel_local.channelname,
channel.channelorder
FROM channel
INNER JOIN channel_local ON
channel.id = channel_local.channelid
WHERE channel.active = 1
AND channel_local.languageid = {defaultlanguageid})
AS channels
```

The results are:

- Channel 1 English Version
- Channel 1 Spanish Version
- Channel 2 English Version

The results Im looking for is

- Channel 1 English Version
- Channel 2 English Version

If the current language is spanish then I would like the result:

- Channel 1 Spanish Version
- Channel 2 English Version (Because there is no spanish version for
  channel 2)

Comment: `ORDER BY` (where English is ordered first) and a `LIMIT 1` on both the SELECTs should work I'd imagine. In SQL Server it's possible to use `GROUP BY` for this, but I don't know how to group-and-take-top-N in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
channel_local.channelid,
channel_local.channelname,
channel.channelorder
FROM channel
INNER JOIN channel_local ON
channel.id = channel_local.channelid
WHERE channel.active = 1
AND channel_local.languageid = {currentlanguageid}
UNION
SELECT 
channel_local.channelid,
channel_local.channelname,
channel.channelorder
FROM channel
INNER JOIN channel_local ON
channel.id = channel_local.channelid
WHERE channel.active = 1
AND channel_local.languageid = {defaultlanguageid})
AS channels
GROUP BY channels.channel_local.channelid
```

Comment: I tried the group by, the problem is the query for defaultlanguageid comes up first.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
SELECT * FROM channel_local
WHERE channelid IN (
    SELECT channelid FROM channel
    WHERE languageid={default language selector}  AND active=1
)
```

simply select all from the `channel_local` where that channel is in the `channel` table and is that `channel` is active

or...

if your active field is in the `channel_local` table you can put

```
SELECT * FROM channel_local
WHERE  active=1 AND channelid IN (
    SELECT channelid FROM channel
    WHERE languageid={default language selector}
)
```

Instead of doing multiple joins, which get very confusing pretty quickly, this correlated subquery may be faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a full union, you can do this:
select channel_local.*, channel.*  from channel_local, channel where  channel.channelid=channel_local.channelid     and  channel_local.channelid in (select channelid from channel where languageid='eng' and active=1)

Comment: Dont know if that will work for what Im looking for. Basically I want to select the entries that is assigned to the current language selected on the site. So if spanish select the entry in channel_local for spanish. However if there is no spanish version it will default to english.